# Java on 64-bit version of Firefox

Tags: java

I was having difficulties in playing videos on youtube. So I updated firefox few days back. Today I updated Java. Installed 64-bit online version of java.

I got this message on java site :

> We have detected you are using the 64-bit version of Firefox which
>   will not run the Java plugin.

So, what now ? Is there a different Java version for 64- bit Firefox ?
Or this firefox does not need java at all ?

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, if this is not, then can anybody direct me to the proper stackexchange site ?

Comment: Java hasn't been supported in Firefox since version 52. It doesn't matter whether it is 64 or 32 bit Java. See [Why do Java, Silverlight, Adobe Acrobat and other plugins no longer work?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugins)

Comment: So, now we do not need those java, flash etc right ?

Comment: Whether you need them or not, they are no longer supported.